# How to write to Sql Server Db on sales_order_place_after trigger

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

I am trying to develop a module that inserts a new row in a Sql Server database (different from magento Mysql databse) with the info from the newplaced order. This is what i have so far:

**in magento/app/etc/modules/Feed_Sales.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
         <Feed_Sales>
             <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
         </Feed_Sales>
     </modules>
</config>
```

**in magento/app/code/local/Feed/Sales/etc/config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <feedsales>
                <class>Feed_Sales_Model</class>
            </feedsales>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                    <feed_sales_order_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>feedsales/order_observer</class>
                        <method>export_new_order</method>
                    </feed_sales_order_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**in magento/app/code/local/Feed/Sales/Model/Order/Observer.php:**

```
<?php
class Feed_Sales_Model_Order_Observer{
    public function __contruct(){

    }

    public function export_new_order($observer){

        $server = 'Example,3320;'
        $link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'password');

        if (!$link) {
            die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
        }

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $order_no = (string) $order->getRealOrderId();
        $order->loadByIncrementId($order_no);
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        $query = "INSERT INTO Order  (id,customerName,address, etc) VALUES   
            ('$order_no', Values to pass)";
        $result = mssql_query($query,$link);

        foreach($items as $i):
            $query = "INSERT INTO OrderItem (orderNumber,name,price,quantity)     VALUES   
                ('$order_no',Values to pass)";
            $result = mssql_query($query,$link)
        endforeach;
    }
}
?>
```

I also need help in knowing how can i access all the details from $order so I can send them to the apropriate fieldsin my database, and the details of $i for the same purpose.

Comment: then what is the issue ?

Comment: "how can i access all the details from $order so I can send them to the apropriate fieldsin my database, and the details of $i for the same purpose"

And if that could possibly work towards my objective. I´m not very experienced in programming in magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have using `sales_order_place_after` event,you can customer data using code:

`$order->getData()` will give you data  in `an array format related` with Customer `order related basic data from db`  tables `sales_flat_order`.

**Also get Item related data from below code:**

```
foreach($items as $item){    
    //item detail     
    echo $item->getItemId(); 
    //product id     
    echo $item->getSku();   
    echo $item->getQtyOrdered(); //ordered qty of item   
    echo $item->getName();     // etc. 

    $query = "INSERT INTO OrderItem (orderNumber,name,price,quantity)     VALUES   
        ('$order_no',Values to pass)";
    $result = mssql_query($query,$link);

}
```